# int from string in go

Tags: go, atoi, parseint

What's the function to create a int value from string

```
i := ???.????( "10" )
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Import the `strconv` package (src/pkg/strconv), then use `strconv.Atoi("10")`

Answer (score 0):

Some other options:

```
package main
import "fmt"

func main() {
   var n int
   fmt.Sscan("100", &n)
   fmt.Println(n == 100)
}
```

```
package main
import "strconv"

func main() {
   n, e := strconv.ParseInt("100", 10, 64)
   if e != nil {
      panic(e)
   }
   println(n == 100)
}
```

- https://golang.org/pkg/fmt#Sscan
- https://golang.org/pkg/strconv#ParseInt